# NS not propagating after about 9 days

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cloudflare, godaddy

About 9 days ago I migrated my Cloudflare hosted site to StablePoint's cPanel cloud hosting. The last step I took was removing my CloudFlare's NS records and adding StablePoint's in GoDaddy's dashboard. Also srv.yiu.ch is still resolvable; I don't know what it may the reason why this is happening.

## What I did:

### before:

yiu.ch with cloudflare NS

- NS srv [stablepoint nameservers]
- CNAME www yiu.ch
- etc...

### then:

deleted cloudflare nameservers via godaddy

### finally:

added stablepoint's NS via godaddy

Thanks in advance.

Please read the comment(s) I wrote

Comment: Is yiu.ch the real domain name? What *should* the NS record show? What is it showing for you?

Comment: At the moment the `yiu.ch` domain is (still) configured with the following 2 authoritative name servers: ns25.domaincontrol.com and ns26.domaincontrol.com , which suggests that you didn't make the correct changes in GoDaddy's dashboard. https://www.godaddy.com/help/edit-my-domain-nameservers-664

Comment: It is a real domain name that I own. Sometime after the post, I changed it to godaddy's nameservers. Then just a few seconds ago I changed it to stablepoint's.